# Null value when looping through Firestore documents in a collection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following function to loop through the documents and their fields that I have in my Firestore collection and display them as a map in the console:

```
documentsLoopFromFirestore() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('myCollection')
      .get()
      .then((idkWhatGoesHereButICantRemoveIt) {
        idkWhatGoesHereButICantRemoveIt.docs.forEach((result) {
      print(result.data());
    });
  });
}
```

When I call `documentsLoopFromFirestore()` in a button with:

```
ElevatedButton(
 onPressed: () {
   print(documentsLoopFromFirestore());
 },
```

I get the following result in the console:

```
I/flutter (29803): null
I/flutter (29803): {lastName: smith, name: peter}
I/flutter (29803): {lastName: doe, name: john}
```

It successfully prints the values of my documents in that Firestore collection, but just before it does so, it throws that `null` that is not allowing my to add this map to another collection which is my objective.

If I add `async` and `await` to the function:

```
documentsLoopFromFirestore() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('myCollection')
      .get()
      .then((idkWhatGoesHereButICantRemoveIt) {
        idkWhatGoesHereButICantRemoveIt.docs.forEach((result) {
      print(result.data());
    });
  });
}
```

Then I get:

```
I/flutter (29803): Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
I/flutter (29803): {lastName: smith, name: peter}
I/flutter (29803): {lastName: doe, name: john}
```

It seems like it throws the `null` when doing the first loop.
Does anyone knows how I can get rid of this `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
this print(documentsLoopFromFirestore());
to documentsLoopFromFirestore(); in ElevatedButton

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see a `null` with the first code and the `Instance od Future<dynamic>` is that you first print out your function and the the result.

In the first case the function soend't return anything so you see `null` and in the second the function is a Furture to you just print that it is a future.

To awoid that either remove the first print or return the values in the format you want in the function.